# How to compare 2 xml files for existence of the field using xslt

Tags: xslt

I have 2 xml files and I want to create output files. So how so I check that both files exist as field of the data, when field of the data has mapped then that should be moved to another file.

Comment: Though I tried answering your questions, it is hard to create a useful answer if you do not show (1) your input, (2) what you tried and where you are stuck and (3) what tools and versions of XSLT you are using. Please have a look at SO's [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

> So how so I check that both files exist

You can only do this with XSLT 2.0. If you are using XSLT 1.0, there is no way without extension functions. In XSLT 2.0, simply use `doc-available('myfile.xml')`.

> as field of the data

This is basic XSLT. You can use any XPath that fits your requirements, but you didn't show input, nor what you tried yourself and where you are stuck. Probably something like:

```
<!-- put this wherever you are processing the data you 
     are referring to but not showing and fix the select 
     statement to your requirements -->
<xsl:apply-templates select="source" />

<xsl:template match="source">
    <!-- the element exists -->
    <xsl:if test="doc-available(source)">
        ...
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

> when field of the data has mapped then that should be moved to another file.

"Another file", meaning a secondary result document? Again, this can only be achieved with XSLT 2.0, unless the processor you are using supports an extension instruction or function that can do this. In XSLT 2.0, just use `xsl:result-document`.